# All my webdrivers aren't working with Selenium, what can I do?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Recently all webdrivers that I try to use don't work correctly, and when I run the same code on another computer it works fine. The problems I get:

- Chrome and Firefox open but stuck at data and then 'selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable' for example;
- Ms Edge won't even open and gives no error;

Already tried: installing and re-installing Selenium, Python, Pycharm, webdrivers of different versions, changed the PATH location, but the problem seems to be in my computer.

Simple code that I am trying to execute:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome() #this is the function that isn't working
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

Any suggestions?

Edit: After two weeks trying to figure it out this issue, the only solution that I found was to reinstall my Windows and all my applications again. Now everything is working as it should, so if anyone else has this problem this is my suggestion.

Thank you all!

Comment: can you try using WebDriver manager please. Is your chrome browser version  103 or 104?

Comment: Already tried using WebDriver manager too. My chrome version is 104.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is OS you are using in which you are trying to run.. are you running from Jenkins in a slave machine.. is chrome.exe in c:/program files/.. or in C:/ users/.. if it in c:/users/.. can you try placing the entire the google folder in c:/program files/.. please or in a place which is commonly accessible by all users and provide same path in your chrome driver manager where you are creating your chrome driver

Comment: I am using Windows 10, not running from Jenkins, and my chrome.exe is located in program files... really don't know what to do, tried msedge and firefox too, but no response from their webdrivers either :/

Comment: _Chrome and Firefox open but stuck at data_, _selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable_,  _Ms Edge won't even open and gives no error_: Please [edit the question](/posts/73390561/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I understand, that's why in the title it says " All my webdrivers... ", the problem it's not only on chrome, but on firefox and msedge too, so I posted the errors related to each browser to exemplify that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but I believe that you need to specify the location of the `ChromeDriver` or Google Chrome `.exe` location before you call your `WebDriver`. Once you specify the location of your `ChromeDriver` then you should be able to use it at your disposal.

**Sample Code For You**

```
from selenium import webdriver

def get_chrome_driver():
    """This sets up our Chrome Driver and returns it as an object"""
    path_to_chrome = "F:\Selenium_Drivers\Windows_Chrome85_Driver\chromedriver.exe"
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    
    # Browser is displayed in a custom window size
    chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1500,1000")

    return webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chrome,
                            options = chrome_options)



# Gets our chrome driver and opens our site
chrome_driver = get_chrome_driver()
chrome_driver.get("https://www.bbc.com/news/world")

chrome_driver.quit()
chrome_driver.service.stop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't work either. Still stuck on "data:;" and recieving the error 'Chrome not reachable'

Comment: @Chernobot - When I go into my Google Chrome Settings ( chrome://settings/help ) , I see that my Chrome Version is `104.0.5112` . So, from there, I went to ( https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads ) and I downloaded the 104 version. After I did that, I just added the `chromedriver.exe` into my designated folder and it worked. Maybe you should try that?

Comment: Already tried the chrome driver for the versions 104 and 105. The problem is that not only on Chrome this error ocurrs, but on other drivers too :/

Comment: Is there any way that we can do a screenshare session? Like a Zoom call or Discord Call? I can probably help you out with that if I can see it myself

Answer (score 0):

when you Intialize the webdriver its always recomended to specify the path of the respective browser like ChromeDriver for Chrome browser and GeckoDriver for Mozilla Firefox.

Or
You can invoke WebDriver manager at the point which would handle this.
Link: https://snyk.io/advisor/python/webdriver-manager

Link: https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager

Answer (score 0):

After two weeks trying to figure it out this issue, the only solution that I found was to reinstall my Windows and all my applications again. Now everything is working as it should, so if anyone else has this problem this is my suggestion.

Thank you all!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).